# Impact to the web application when converting a local directory on to a NAS

Tags: java, linux, weblogic, nas

We have a web application running at this point on Linux and weblogic setup.
There is one local directory /home/doc which stores the files used in our application.

At present, we make a call to this location via 
Wls: virtual url mapping and wls:localPath in the weblogic configuration file.

My query is if this directory is pointing to NAS instead of local will this still work?
Also we access this path via our App url like this: https:///root/home/doc

This url is unprotected from the security authentication.

Will there be any impact to this? Can someone please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does not matter if the directory is on block storage or NFS/NAS so long as weblogic can read the files it will work just fine.